# FILTER array and COUNTIF/loop counter

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

This is basically a continuation of my previous question. But my intended output is outlined in a sample Google Sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k1wQqATlhOuS_ztqtpz3FERVY-g-34rIDARbfOwdtV4/edit?usp=sharing

The intention is there is Control Number in `Form Responses 1` Sheet `COLUMN AC` that serves as a tracker and a search key. Form submissions can add an update or close that Control Number which is indicated in `COLUMNs B and C`. I would like to add a number appended to `UPDATE TICKET` in `COLUMN B` entries when they are filtered and added to a collated data entry similar in `Sheet 1`.

My problem arises when using `COUNTIFS` or `COUNTIFS` since the general forumula in `Sheet 1` has dissimilar array sizes (and thus a `CONCAT` error) and the `COUNTIF` does not count the per element of the filtered array (in the sample sheet, it only appends 2 to all entries.

```
=arrayformula(filter('Form Responses 1'!$B2:$B,'Form Responses 1'!$C2:C=INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$C2:$C,COUNTA('Form Responses 1'!$A2:A),0))&" "&IFERROR(COUNTIF(filter('Form Responses 1'!$B2:$B,'Form Responses 1'!$C2:C=INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$C2:$C,COUNTA('Form Responses 1'!$A2:A),0),'Form Responses 1'!$B2:$B="UPDATE TICKET"),filter('Form Responses 1'!$B2:$B,'Form Responses 1'!$C2:C=INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$C2:$C,COUNTA('Form Responses 1'!$A2:A),0),'Form Responses 1'!$B2:$B="UPDATE TICKET")),"")&":"&" "&filter(TEXT('Form Responses 1'!$H2:$H,"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm"),'Form Responses 1'!$C2:C=INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$C2:$C,COUNTA('Form Responses 1'!$A2:A),0))&char(10))
```

I also tried adding `COUNTIFS` additonal rule condition such as `row(filteredarray),=<row(filterearray)` to output the intedend counter 1,2,3, etc. per match (similar to how the control number works) of the `UPDATE TICKET` but the `ROW` function doesn't seem to accept filtered array as a cell reference. Lastly, I want to omit the counter on the last entry which is a `CLOSE TICKET`. I detailed my trials and the intended output in the linked Google Sheets.

Comment: Did you intend to share the sample as View Only? we can't test or demonstrate solutions without editing rights.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I thought that was the common practice where people just copy the sample sheet, or is that not possible when viewing only?

Comment: yeah, no worries, just a bunch of people all working apart is all.  I always thought that was inefficient.  I've got a copy, here that people can feel free to use:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0e5tM2KmGTu5NdJVwSZMqT5Xs-XhUQJK-9ECE1u7tM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Output]

Form Reponses 1 - AE2

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C2:C="",,"UPDATE TICKET "&COUNTIFS(C:C,C2:C,ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))&": "&TEXT(A2:A,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")))
```

Sheet1

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(FILTER({'Form Responses 1'!C:C&"♥",'Form Responses 1'!AE:AE&"♦"},'Form Responses 1'!B:B="UPDATE TICKET"),"select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1",),,10^7)),"♥"),"(?:^\s*)|(?:\s*(♦)\s*)|(?:♦\s*$)","$1"),"♦",CHAR(10)))
```

Comment: The first item in `COLUMN AE` is not the exact solution that I was looking for but I guess it can be a good alternative and just collate the answers from `COLUMN AE`.

Comment: `AE` is only a helper column, have you checked the screenshot and `Sheet1`?

Answer (score 1):

It was difficult to follow what you'd done so far, but you were clear with your goal, so i redid what I needed to to get there.  Any formulas in yellow are mine.  You'll find this solution on the [tab called MK.Help](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0e5tM2KmGTu5NdJVwSZMqT5Xs-XhUQJK-9ECE1u7tM/edit?usp=sharing) in cell A2.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(MID(QUERY({"00000"&Form!C2:C&Form!AD2:AD&":|",TEXT(ROW(Form!A2:A),"00000")&Form!AE2:AE&": "&TEXT(IF(Form!H2:H,Form!H2:H,Form!A2:A),"m/d/yy h:mm")&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),Form!B2:B},"select MAX(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"),6,100),,9^9)),"|")),CHAR(10)&" ",CHAR(10)))
```